# How can I add an hyperlink in status bar notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I have some html text in status bar notification and it is properly displaying in status bar text (with the formatting).   I also have a link in text that should open the url when clicked.    how can I do this?

the content of status bar notifiction is actually a resonse (html text) from some webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not allow to do notifications without reaction on click. So you can do like this:

```
Notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(YOUR_URL_HERE)),0);
```

I think it's not the best idea to do link only on text, because it's hard to click on i with finger.